# Bank/broker that offers no credit cards (ally.com/vanguard.com)?

Tags: debt

Is there a bank/broker that offers no credit cards? Are ally.com and
vanguard.com good choices?

I'm considering debt settlement, and have been advised to open a
bank/brokerage account not owned by one of my creditors. To play it
safe, I'd like to find one that offers NO credit cards whatsoever.

Are ally.com and/or vanguard.com good choices? Notes:

- In some cases, it's easy to identify bank affiliation. For
  example, I have a Compass credit card, so a Compass bank account
  wouldn't work.
- In other cases, however, it's quite difficult. For example, I have
  a Capital One credit card, so ING Direct won't work, since ING
  Direct is now owned by Capital Group.

It's the second case I'm worried about. Do ally.com/vanguard.com issue
credit cards through some other affiliated company? If so, what are
some good non-credit-card-issuing banks?

Comment: Have you considered a credit union?

Comment: nmefcu.org is a local credit union, but I have a credit card from them as well.

Comment: What about looking into a different credit union?

Comment: Are you sure Vanguard offers the services you need? They have a number of low-cost ETFs and mutual funds, but if you're looking for a checking or savings account, they may not be a fit.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say look around your town and find a local bank. As in, a small regional bank. There are thousands of them, so it shouldn't be too hard to find.Then call and ask if they offer a credit card. Some do, some don't. Any national-scale or international bank will, though, as far as I know.

Comment: "There are thousands of them" ... I'd laugh if it weren't so sad. Most "local" banks I've found (in Albuquerque at least) are owned/operated by the big national banks.

Comment: @barrycarter here's a list of 380 of them that are listed on the stock exchange. http://www.google.com/finance?catid=56630876

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, ally.com is a great option. They offer great rates, dead simple application and management website and have great customer support to boot.

From a quick look at their wiki, it doesn't seem like they would venture into credit cards.

Comment: Ally is a rename of GMAC. They offer credit cards, as do almost all banks.